# Replacing self.view with new UIView shows black view

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to change the existing view in a UIViewController to a new view. The new view contains the old view and a little banner view.

Doing this fairly simple change leaves me with a black view.

My code looks like this

```
UIView *existingView = self.view;
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:existingView.frame];
UIView *bannerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (self.view.frame.size.height - 50), 320, 50)];

CGRect existingViewFrame = existingView.frame;
existingViewFrame.size.height -= 50;
existingView.frame = existingViewFrame;

[newView addSubview:existingView];
[newView addSubview:bannerView];

self.view = newView;
```

However when switch Tabs and come back to the view which changed the view is shown just like I want. I guess I need to set a flag or something to tell the controller to redraw it's (new) view.

**Edit**

I wrote an simple example for this problem. You can find it on GitHub: https://github.com/Oemera/ChangeView

Comment: In order to force the view to redraw just call `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]` at the end. That should do the trick.

Comment: Try that but it doesn't work. Also tried '[self.view layoutIfNeeded]' but it also doesn't work as I hoped. Any other suggestions?

Comment: changing the root view anywhere but loadView is messy, what are you trying to achieve with this? there are probably better ways to do it

Comment: Thank you. This is a really good advice. I changed the root view in a method which is called when an iAd is ready. I now have changed this behavior. I now use a UIView with a UITableView inside instead of using just a UITableView. This gives me the chance to just add the ADBanner to the root view as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say where you do this. It may be that you need to save the original view's super view, then add the new view to that views subViews array. I'm betting that is the problem.

Comment: I did this in a delegate method. Every time a iAd banner is loaded this methods gets called. Changing the root view in a given state after loadView seems not a good idea. I changed this behavior now. If you want to see the "broken" code which shows the black view checkout the GitHub repo.

Comment: I can't look at your code right now but for sure you should either assert or print huge debug message if when you set self.view = new view at the end, if self.view.superview is set. Also the system sets self.view.window so not sure if you need to fool with the window property too. If you search on SO you might find a specific QnA of how to swap out a viewController's view. I only do that in viewDidLoad not afterwards.